# What are most impact jsperf tests?

Tags: javascript, jsperf

Is there any website organizing jsperf test by its impact on programming? If not, do you found some test, I would notice?

Answer (score 4):

JSPerf has a popular section though not all of these are impactful I'm sure:

http://jsperf.com/popular

Comment: Not impactful and not many. I know about them.